# Please critique my proof of Heine-Borel

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing

Here is a proof of Heine-Borel that is different from the proof in the Schaum's workbook that I'm using. I'm wondering if it is valid, please critique. Also some of my braces ("{" and "}") didn't render after escaping them with a slash, so if anyone has advice, please let me know.

I will attempt to prove the simple case of the compact set $ X=[a,b] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Since scaling and shifting operations don't change whether a set is open or closed, we can WOLOG work with the simpler set $X=[0,1].$

Let $\{G_{i \in \mathbb{N}}\}$ be an infinite open cover of $X$. There must be an open set covering the point 0, so its intersection with $X $ is $ [0,x_1)$. Call this interval $F_1$. If $x_1 > 1$ then we are done, so assume $x_1 \le 1.$ The point $x_1$ must also be covered by one of the open sets, say some interval $(d, x_2)  $ (we don't care what the first coordinate is), and then set $F_2$ equal to the union of those two intervals so that $F_2=[0,x_2).$ Similarly, if $x_2>1$ we are done, so assume otherwise. Then continue in this fashion creating a sequence of nested intervals $F_i=[0,x_i).$ If any of the $x_i$ are larger than one we are done, so assume that none of them are. Then the $\{F_i\}$ converge to $[0,1)$ for if not, just repeat the same argument on whatever interval they converge to. We have an infinite subcover of $[0, 1)$ at this point. But there is also a $G_i $ which covers 1, call it $G_1$. $G_1=(1-\delta, 1+\epsilon), $ so since 1 is an accumulation point of $[0,1]$, infinitely many of the $x_i$ are in $[1-\delta, 1]. $ ***<strike>Thus, after taking the intersection of the $F_i$ with $G_1$, infinitely many of the $F_i$ can be removed, leaving a finite sub-cover.</strike>***  $ \square$

Edit: @K Jiang spotted an error in the last sentence. What about this: **Thus there will be a finite number of $F_i$ for which $lub(F_i) \le 1-\delta$. That finite subset of the $F_i$ with $G_1$ added will constitute a finite subcover**. $\square$

I just realized I also have to account for the same issue when I say "repeat the same interval on whatever interval they converge to" since I would also need to prove that there are a finite number of such instances of that happening.

Comment: Generally speaking, questions on Math SE need to be fairly narrowly focused. Questions like "Is my proof correct?" are generally too broad to be appropriate for this site. If you can focus your question on a *key step* that you are confused about, please edit the question so that focus is more clear. Otherwise, I would suggest that you take this up with someone who is, e.g., responsible for grading your work (since you are essentially asking us to grade your proof for you).

Comment: What if no one is grading it because I am self-studying?

Comment: The fact that you are self-studying does not make an off-topic question on-topic.  Math SE exists to create a repository of questions and answers which are likely to be useful to not only the original asker, but to future readers, as well.  This is *not* a discussion forum, nor a homework grading service.  If you are looking for someone to assess your work, this isn't the right place.  There might be some other place on the internet where you can get help (maybe reddit?).

Comment: Removing an infinite number of elements from an infinite set does not guarantee that you end up with a finite set.